# no spaces while printing the output after reading the file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the contents of the file to output but the output is missing the spaces from the file.
I've also tried using infile >> noskipws >> ch; but it displays only the first word from the file.

```
int process_infile(int shift)
{   
    char c[1000];
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("D:\\example.txt") ;
    if(!ifile)
    {
        //cout<<"Error in opening file..!!";
        error();
        //getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    cout<<"Data in file = ";
    while(ifile.eof()==0)
    {
        ifile >> c;
        cout << c;
        //encodeCaesarCipher(c,shift);
    }       
    ifile.close();
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `ifile >> c` skips spaces, then reads a word (up to the next space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
while(ifile.eof()==0)
{
  string line;
  getline(ifile,line);
  cout << line;
        //encodeCaesarCipher(c,shift);
}
```